# I told her what you insisted that we need. [relative or interrogative pronoun?]

Tags: relative-pronouns, questions

This is an example from The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language by Huddlestone and Pullum, on page 1088:

> [i] I told her **what** you insisted that we need.

There, they're discussing the location of the gap in an unbounded dependency construction.

At the bottom of the page, it says,

> The meaning of [i] can be given as "I told her the value of x in the proposition 'You insisted that we need x'"...

Now, in context, is "**what**" a relative pronoun or an interrogative pronoun?

Comment: It doesn't look like an interrogative pronoun to me since it's not part of a question.

Answer (score 1):

By the reckoning of the authors:

> The meaning of [i] can be given as "I told her the value of x in the proposition 'You insisted that we need x'"..

**What** is a relative pronoun that serves as the object of both

> *I told* (her)

and

> *we need*

as in

> *I told* (her) **ten pence**

and

> *We need* **ten pence**